# how to hide and show image and text tags according to values returned from array loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am trying to create a questionnaire here. The questions and options are being fetched from a database via API. Some of the options to choose from will be images. I inserted the image link to my database. I am looking for a way to hide text and show image if the option is an image and also show text and hide image if the option is a text

What i have tried so far;
my image link looks like something like this: "../../folder/img.jpg" so i recognize an image link by the first two parts of the string.
I already tried iterating over the options with a for each loop like this:

```
imgOption: boolean = false;
textOption: boolean = false;

this.opts.forEach(element => {
  if ( element.slice(0, 2) == ".." ) {
    this.imgOption = true;
    this.textOption = false;
  } else {
    this.imgOption = false;
    this.textOption = true;
  }
});
```

But then, the whole value comes out as text

[display result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDRf4.png)

Here is my template file:

```
<ul *ngFor = "let o of opts; let i = index">
  <li (click)='onSelect(o, i)' id="{{i}}">
    <span *ngIf='textOption'>{{o}}</span>
    <img *ngIf='imgOption' src="{{o}}" alt="img" class="imgOption">
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want the loop to return `true` or `false` to only the index that matches the condition stated and not display everything as an image or text. Please how do I go about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are changing your `imgOption` and `textOption` variable for every element, so it will take the value of the last element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a method to check whether it is a img option or text option inside your for loop. For example,

```
<ul *ngFor = "let o of opts; let i = index">
  <li (click)='onSelect(o, i)' id="{{i}}">
    <span *ngIf="checkOption('text',o)">{{o}}</span>
<img *ngIf="checkOption('img',o)" src="{{o}}" alt="img" class="imgOption"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can use that method to return true or false.

```
checkOption(type,o) {
    if(type="img"){
     if ( o.slice(0, 2) == ".." ) {
      return true;
    }else { return false;}
    } else {
    if ( o.slice(0, 2) == ".." ) {
      return false;
    }else { return true;}
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Your array needs to store the show/hide state for each value, rather than having one variable set for all.

```
opts = [{imageOption: true, value: '../mylink.jpg'}, {imageOption: false, value: 'another value'}];

this.opts.forEach(element => {
  if ( element.slice(0, 2) == ".." ) {
    element.imageOption = true;
  } else {
    element.imageOption = false;
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<ul *ngFor = "let o of opts; let i = index">
  <li (click)='onSelect(o, i)' id="{{i}}">
    <span *ngIf='!o.imageOption'>{{o.value}}</span>
    <img *ngIf='o.imageOption' src="{{o.value}}" alt="img" class="imgOption">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage imgOption and textOption for every opts elements, in your case variable is element.
You can follow below code where "element.value" is equivalent to your previous variable "element" and fix html code accordingly.

```
this.opts.forEach(element => {
  if ( element.value.slice(0, 2) == ".." ) {
    element.imgOption = true;
    element.textOption = false;
  } else {
    element.imgOption = false;
    element.textOption = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar requirement in my old project easiest way to go about this is to add two new properties imgOption and textOption to your Options model in UI and for each option value returned update imgOption and textOption according to your condition
once you make this changes your code should look something like below

```
    this.opts.forEach(element => {
     if ( element.value.slice(0, 2) == ".." ) {
       element.imgOption = true;
       element.textOption = false;
     } else {
        element.imgOption = false;
        element.textOption = true;
     }
   });
```

HTML should be

```
<ul *ngFor = "let o of opts; let i = index">
  <li (click)='onSelect(o, i)' id="{{i}}">
    <span *ngIf='o.textOption'>{{o}}</span>
    <img *ngIf='o.imgOption' src="{{o}}" alt="img" class="imgOption">
  </li>
</ul>
```